# Django REST Framework - Filtering against the URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST Framework toolkit with Django 1.11 and I am trying to filter the results against the url.  Here is my setup:

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Package(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Package

class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Package
            fields = ('name',)
```

**views.py**:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Package
from .serializers import PackageSerializer

class PackageViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = PackageSerializer
     queryset = Package.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'package', views.PackageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Currently when I use this I can filter the results by the id field:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/package/1/
```

I am hoping to filter the results by the name field of my package model instead by using this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/package/basic/
```

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `lookup_field` attribute in the viewset, see [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes).

```
class PackageViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

Comment: And I thought Google was fast... thank you for the quick reply and the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter_fields in views.

```
filter_fields = ('name',)
```

lookup field is used to set lookup by default it would be **model** `pk`

if you wish to make your URL,

```
my_url/filter_field/
```

set `lookup_field = "name"`

if you want search from URL like ,

```
my_url/?name=something
```

you need to set `filter_fields` in views.